# npm install failed in angular 7

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

i am running above command to install missing npm packages it gives below error while installing npm
  node-sass@4.10.0 install F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass

> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
    Cannot download "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.13.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)     
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +   
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +        
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +      
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)     
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)     
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +   
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +       
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +        
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher 
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location 
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\TPL\\TFS\\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\\Src\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd F:\TPL\TFS\AdminPortal-branch-v1.0.0\Src\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @angular/animations@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.15 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@7.2.15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

 please let me know if any one also facing same issue i have been stuck in this error since long time
```

Comment: you need to configure the right proxy inside .npmrc. This is related to how proxy has been configured.

Comment: how to set proxy in .npmrc ?

Comment: you might have to use the command `npm config set https-proxy with the proxy specified` and run it one more time for http-proxy.

Comment: why i need to set as it give me same error on my personal network which dose't have any proxy setting

Comment: I am not quite sure about the proxy that you are behind. But I am guessing one of your devs might have already faced this scenario.

Comment: sometimes even your local network might have some kind of proxy in place which might be the cause behind.

Comment: but iam not able to diagnose it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207346/discussion-between-mkant-and-umer-safeer).

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`npm install --global windows-build-tools` and then `npm install`

Comment: ihave run npm install --global windows-build-tools and it gives below error             
 ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080  
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: If you are using corporal network you should set proxy with npm
npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port> 

npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>

Comment: Maybe this will help 
npm cache verify

Comment: Check for node-sass if its globally installed if not try to install it.